Which paper is the "Taubes trick" from?
In symplectic geometry, the "Taubes trick" is an argument used to show that a moduli space $\mathcal{M}(J)$, depending on a parameter $J \in \mathcal{J}$, is cut out transversely for generic choices of $J$. To elaborate, the usual Sard–Smale argument only proves that $\mathcal{M}(J)$ is cut out transversely for generic $J$ in some Banach completion $\mathcal{J}^k$ of the parameter space $\mathcal{J}$. The Taubes trick (roughly) involves choosing a compact exhaustion $\mathcal{M}_1(J) \subseteq \mathcal{M}_2(J) \subseteq \cdots$ of each $\mathcal{M}(J)$ and noting that, by virtue of compactness, each $\mathcal{M}_i(J)$ is cut out transversely for a comeager subset of $\mathcal{J}^k$ which is also open. Since $\mathcal{J}$ is a dense subset of $\mathcal{J}^k$, it follows that $\mathcal{M}_i(J)$ is cut out transversely for an open and dense subset of $\mathcal{J}$, hence $\mathcal{M}(J) = \bigcup_i \mathcal{M}_i(J)$ is cut out transversely for a comeager subset of $\mathcal{J}$.
I have found several sources which attribute this argument to Taubes, e.g., McDuff & Salamon's book on $J$-holomorphic curves and Chris Wendl's various lecture notes. However, none of these sources cite the original paper where this argument is from. Does anyone know where I can find the original source for the "Taubes trick"?

The established reference (see for example arXiv:0912.0651) to Taubes trick is

C.H. Taubes, Seiberg Witten and Gromov invariants for symplectic 4-manifolds (2000).

This book collects results from four papers by Taubes, including

C.H. Taubes, Counting
pseudo-holomorphic submanifolds in dimension 4,     J.
Differential Geom. 44, 818–893 (1996).


It seems that this answer is not entirely correct (but it leads to the right answer!). The paper you linked, when outlining the Taubes trick, states that the details can be found in McDuff & Salamon's book "J-holomorphic Curves and Quantum Cohomology" from 1994. That book further cites Taubes as follows: "[81] C. Taubes, Personal Communication." So the original source is not a written one!
